# Get position of current Hovered element

Tags: jquery, css

Here's the original page: http://demetra-bk.kz

Here's my JS code:

```
    $('#block-views-hot-deals-block .views-row').hover(function() {
        var $CurClass = $(this).attr('class');
        var $ResClass = $CurClass.replace(/views-row\s(views-row-\d{1,2})\s.+/, '$1');
        var $PosTop = $(this).offset().top - $('#block-views-hot-deals-block').offset().top;
        var $PosLeft = $(this).offset().left - $('#block-views-hot-deals-block').offset().left;
        console.log($PosTop);
        $('#hover-divs .' + $ResClass).css({display: 'block', top: $PosTop, left: $PosLeft});

        // saving vars for further use
        $(this).data('resclass', $ResClass);
    }, function() {
        $('#hover-divs .' + $(this).data('resclass')).css('display', 'none');
    });
```

When i hover on element with class "views-row" in a parent div "#block-views-hot-deals-block" i want to get position of current hovered element and use it on a hidden div, however, when i hover now, i get a blinking div. Can someone help me figure out?

**UPDATE1**

When i change the values:

```
 var $PosTop = $(this).offset().top - $('#block-views-hot-deals-block .content').offset().top;
 var $PosLeft = $(this).offset().left;
```

It works smooth, but calculating left position relative to document, not my parent div with `position: relative`..

Comment: Its bit hard to tell without trying few things, but i think if u donot set top it will not blink , just make block and set left.

Comment: You're wrong, even if i remove top it still blinking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
    $('#block-views-hot-deals-block .views-row').mouseenter(function() {
        var $CurClass = $(this).attr('class');
        var $ResClass = $CurClass.replace(/views-row\s(views-row-\d{1,2})\s.+/, '$1');

        var $PosTop = $(this).offset().top - $('#block-views-hot-deals-block .content').offset().top;
        var $PosLeft = $(this).offset().left - $('#block-views-hot-deals-block .content').offset().left;
        console.log($PosLeft);

        $('#hover-divs .' + $ResClass).css({display: 'block', top: $PosTop - 25, left: $PosLeft - 28});

        // saving vars for further use
        $(this).data('resclass', $ResClass);
    });
    $('#hover-divs .views-row').mouseleave(function() {
        //$('#hover-divs .' + $(this).data('resclass')).css({display: 'none'});
        $(this).css({display: 'none'});
    });
```

Use `.mouseenter()` and `.mouseleave()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

First of if you want to get position of current hovered element `.views-row` you don't need to subtract `#block-views-hot-deals-block` position on it. jQuery's `offset()` already returns the coordinates of the element **relative to the document**.

The blinking occurs because when hover-in is triggered you are setting the `#hover-divs` in front or on top of the `.views-row` element, so suddenly the mouse pointer is now hovered on the `#hover-divs` and not on `.views-row` anymore. So moving the mouse makes it blink because hover is being fired over and over again. Here, I replicate the problem on this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yLDnt/

A solution would be to **append** the `#hover-divs` in the `.views-row` upon hover. Although the mouse will still be hovering the `#hover-divs` but this element is now a child of `.views-row` and the hover event won't fire again.

```
$('#hover-divs .' + $ResClass).appendTo($(this))//the current hovered element
 .css({display: 'block', top: $PosTop, left: $PosLeft});
```

See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yLDnt/1/

As opposed to this, I think a much better UI and UX is to set the `#hover-divs` position relative to the mouse' coordinate on `mousemove` event, so it moves when the mouse moves. Take a look at this jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yLDnt/2/.

Comment: Thanks for your deep explanations, i have set: .appendTo($(this)), but however, when i hover now - it shows hidden divs in incorrect place. You can see it on my site now.

Comment: And i think .appendTo($(this)) is not correct in my case, because then it will show original div on hover not a hidden one.